crash on Windows without Intel's oneAPI setvars called
On Windows 10 I have Visual Studio 22 and Intel oneAPI 24.4. I use MSVC and the classic ifort Intel Fortran compiler.
My command line application compiles and runs fine when oneAPI is activated via setvars.
Without calling setvars, the following redistributable libs are missing: mkl_intel_thread.2.dll, libiomp5md.dll, libifcoremd.dll, libmmd.dll, svml_dispmd.dll
When I copy them to my bin directory, no missing dlls are shown, but the application exits silently.
When I run with lldb, I get the following stack trace
Process 2720 stopped                                                                 
* thread #1, stop reason = Exception 0xc06d007e encountered at address 0x7fff2ac1b699
    frame #0: 0x00007fff2ac1b699 KernelBase.dll`RaiseException + 105                 
KernelBase.dll`RaiseException:                                                       
->  0x7fff2ac1b699 <+105>: nopl   (%rax,%rax)                                        
    0x7fff2ac1b69e <+110>: movq   0xc0(%rsp), %rcx                                   
    0x7fff2ac1b6a6 <+118>: xorq   %rsp, %rcx                                         
    0x7fff2ac1b6a9 <+121>: callq  0x7fff2ac767a0 ; RemoveDllDirectory + 112          
(lldb) bt                                                                            
* thread #1, stop reason = Exception 0xc06d007e encountered at address 0x7fff2ac1b699
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff2ac1b699 KernelBase.dll`RaiseException + 105
    frame #1: 0x00007ffeb35f414e mkl_intel_thread.2.dll`mkl_serv_free + 1358
    frame #2: 0x00007ffeb35f3ad5 mkl_intel_thread.2.dll`mkl_serv_lock + 69
    frame #3: 0x00007ff6efc83638 cfs.exe`void boost::serialization::singleton_module::unlock(void) + 317416
    frame #4: 0x00007ff6efc82067 cfs.exe`void boost::serialization::singleton_module::unlock(void) + 311831
    frame #5: 0x00007ff6efc6e115 cfs.exe`void boost::serialization::singleton_module::unlock(void) + 230085
    frame #6: 0x00007ff6efc2b98a cfs.exe
    frame #7: 0x00007ff6efc3657a cfs.exe`void boost::serialization::singleton_module::unlock(void) + 1834
    frame #8: 0x00007ff6f090f22c cfs.exe`int boost::archive::codecvt_null<wchar_t>::do_out(struct _Mbstatet &, wchar_t const *, wchar_t const *, wchar_t const *&, char *, char *, char
 *&) const + 123356
    frame #9: 0x00007fff2b337374 kernel32.dll`BaseThreadInitThunk + 20
    frame #10: 0x00007fff2d0fcc91 ntdll.dll`RtlUserThreadStart + 33
(lldb)

But with setvars it works. What could be missing, what is set by setvars?
